# Bind function arguments in Julia

Tags: julia, function-binding

Does Julia provide something similar to [`std::bind`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) in C++? I wish to do something along the lines of:

```
function add(x, y)
  return x + y
end


add45 = bind(add, 4, 5)
add2 = bind(add, _1, 2)
add3 = bind(add, 3, _2)
```

And if this is possible does it incur any performance overhead?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536525/is-there-a-way-in-julia-to-modify-a-function-fx-such-that-it-will-return-fx answer your question? If yes I would close this as duplicate.

Comment: the `bind` function you provide does answer the questions. Does this incur a performance penalty (even if using `const`)?

Comment: This is a valid question and I can answer it here :) (just not to close your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536525/is-there-a-way-in-julia-to-modify-a-function-fx-such-that-it-will-return-fx) you can obtain this behavior using higher order functions in Julia.

Regarding the performance. There should be no overhead. Actually the compiler should inline everything in such a situation and even perform constant propagation (so that the code could actually be faster). The use of `const` in the other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68536525/is-there-a-way-in-julia-to-modify-a-function-fx-such-that-it-will-return-fx) is needed only because we are working in global scope. If all this would be used within a function then `const` is not required (as the function that takes this argument will be properly compiled), so in the example below I do not use `const`.

Let me give an example with `Base.Fix1` and your `add` function:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> function add(x, y)
         return x + y
       end
add (generic function with 1 method)

julia> add2 = Base.Fix1(add, 10)
(::Base.Fix1{typeof(add), Int64}) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> y = 1:10^6;

julia> @btime add.(10, $y);
  1.187 ms (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)

julia> @btime $add2.($y);
  1.189 ms (2 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

Note that I did not define `add2` as `const` and since we are in global scope I need to prefix it with `$` to interpolate its value into the benchmarking suite.

If I did not do it you would get:

```
julia> @btime add2.($y);
  1.187 ms (6 allocations: 7.63 MiB)
```

Which is essentially the same timing and memory use, but does 6 not 2 allocations since in this case `add2` is a type-unstable global variable.

I work on DataFrames.jl, and there using the patterns which we discuss here is very useful. Let me give just one example:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = 1:5)
5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
   3 │     3
   4 │     4
   5 │     5

julia> filter(:x => <(2.5), df)
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     2
```

What the operation does is picking rows where values from column `:x` that are less than `2.5`. The key thing to understand here is what `<(2.5)` does. It is:

```
julia> <(2.5)
(::Base.Fix2{typeof(<), Float64}) (generic function with 1 method)
```

so as you can see it is similar to what we would have obtained if we defined the `x -> x < 2.5` function (essentially fixing the second argument of `<` function, as in Julia `<` is just a two argument function). Such shortcuts like `<(2.5)` above are defined in Julia by default for several common comparison operators.